# Unable to send push notification from flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
 static sendNotificationToDriver(
      String token, context, String ride_request_id) async {
    print("Token =" + token);
    print("RIDE REQUEST =" + ride_request_id);
    Map<String, String> headerMap = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': serverToken,
    };

    Map notificationMap = {
      'body': 'DropOff Address, "Destination',
      'title': 'New Ride Request'
    };

    Map dataMap = {
      'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      'id': '1',
      'status': 'done',
      'ride_request_id': ride_request_id,
    };

    Map sendNotificationMap = {
      "notification": notificationMap,
      "data": dataMap,
      "priority": "high",
      "to": token,
    };

    // var res = await http.post(
    //   Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
    //   headers: headerMap,
    //   body: jsonEncode(sendNotificationMap),
    // );

    try {
      print("try for messaging");
      await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: headerMap,
        body: jsonEncode(sendNotificationMap),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("error firebase messaging = " + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I am trying to send notification to a single device using FCM token. have all the data and everything good to go, but i am unable to recieve the notification on the device.

When I use POSTMAN it works fine but not working programmatically.

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Above given is the code I am trying to work with. It works fine on the POSTMAN but not working from the code in flutter.

Comment: Can you share response of sending push notification please ? If it is showing success then this code should be fine otherwise you must be getting some error like invalidtoken or anything

Comment: The response code is 401. I have already enabled the APIs and it works fine on Postman